# How to put files directly in the directory?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a possibility to put a file (specifically a Json list) in the directory during the development of the application, other than through the user interface? I tried to put this file in the assets and then import it into a List in the code (the same list that is used for the directory), however when I deleted it, it would appear again. I wish someone could help me.I don't know if I could explain well...

Comment: Do you want to put a file on device's memory during runtime? Your question is quite unclear

Comment: I have a list.builder that is being built according to what the user adds, it is a list of reminders with a checkbox. I would like to know if it is possible for me to put "fixed" reminders, reminders that come when starting the app (but with the possibility of deleting the same as the user adds)

Comment: So you want to persist some tabular-like data on user's device?

Comment: yes.............

Comment: What you're trying to acheive is very simple , use Shared_Preferences package . link: https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences